# iOS - Dynamic height, data driven, vertically scrollable layout

Tags: ios, swift, ios-autolayout

I am trying to create the layout in the image

[image]

Here is the main requirements:

- The content in each section is data driven and retrieved from the api.
- The height of each section is dynamic, based on how many fields we have.
- The scene height is dynamic.
- The scene is vertically scrollable.

Here is what I tried to do:
 - Using static cell UITableView
 - Using stack view with a scroll view

In both cases I got stuck with dealing with stack views for the dynamic data fields, and I struggled in handling the dynamic height for each section.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is pretty straight forward and can be met using a `UITableView`. Use dynamic `UITableViewCell`. The reason i choose dynamic table view cell is that you can resize the cell height according to content. Measure your content size inside the [`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview?language=objc).

The flow will be following:

1. Initiate the api call
2. While the data isn't available return the cell height according to your placeholder view (i.e placeholder image height)
3. While the data is available, process your data and reload the table view
4. After reloading the table view, table view will ask each cell's height once again, so this is the chance you get to calculate the content height. (I assume that you can measure the string height while the string width and font is given. Plz google that, thats obvious.)
5. return that calculated height.

**Optimization Possibilities:**
Instead of recalculating the cell height each time, you can calculate the cell height once and store that height inside a simple dictionary keyed with `IndexPath`.